# How can I make this code asks each question once?

Tags: prolog

**I'm trying this code on SWI-Prolog:**

```
go :-
    write('What is the patient''s name? '),
    read(Patient),
    hypothesis(Patient,Disease),
    write_list([Patient,'probably has ',Disease,'.']),nl.
go :-
    write('Sorry, I don''t seem to be able to'),nl,
    write('diagnose the disease.'),nl.

symptom(Patient,fever) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a fever (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,rash) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a rash (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,headache) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a headache (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,runny_nose) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a runny_nose (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a conjunctivitis (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,cough) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a cough (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,body_ache) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a body_ache (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,chills) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a chills (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,sore_throat) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a sore_throat (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,sneezing) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a sneezing (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,swollen_glands) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a swollen_glands (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).
hypothesis(Patient,german_measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).
hypothesis(Patient,flu) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,cough).
hypothesis(Patient,common_cold) :-
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,chills).
hypothesis(Patient,mumps) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,swollen_glands).
hypothesis(Patient,chicken_pox) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,rash).
hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose).

write_list([]).
write_list([Term| Terms]) :-
    write(Term),
    write_list(Terms).

response(Reply) :-
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, Codes),
    nth0(0, Codes, FirstCode),
    char_code(Reply, FirstCode).

**And sometimes and randomly it asks the same question multiple times when it was already answered. Help please.**
```

Comment: Search SO with `[prolog] hypothesis is:answer` ([results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+hypothesis+is%3Aanswer)) - I don't plan to find the specific one you need but it should be in that list.

Comment: Why is `measles` in the head two hypothesis predicates? In other words you have to hypothesis that list different symptoms for `measles`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic predicate to store the answers to questions that have been asked before. Thus, when the system is verifying a hypothesis, it will not repeat the questions that were already asked during the verification of hypotheses that have already been verified previously.

```
:- dynamic symptom/3.

go :-
    retractall(symptom(_, _, _)), % clear the database
    write('What is the patient''s name? '),
    read_atom(Patient),
    hypothesis(Patient,Disease),
    write_list([Patient,' probably has ', Disease, '.']),
    nl.

go :-
    write('Sorry, I don''t seem to be able to'),nl,
    write('diagnose the disease.'),nl.

read_atom(Atom) :-
    read_line_to_string(user_input, String), % <== EDIT: user_input instead of user
    atom_string(Atom, String).

symptom(Patient, Symptom) :-
    (   symptom(Patient, Symptom, Answer)                              % If the answer is already known
    ->  true                                                           % then don't ask it again
    ;   write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a ', Symptom, ' (y/n)? ']), % else ask the question
        read_atom(Answer),                                             % read the answer and
        assertz(symptom(Patient, Symptom, Answer))                     % store it into the database
    ),
    Answer = y.

hypothesis(Patient, measles) :-
    symptom(Patient, fever),
    symptom(Patient, cough),
    symptom(Patient, conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient, runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient, rash).

hypothesis(Patient, german_measles) :-
    symptom(Patient, fever),
    symptom(Patient, headache),
    symptom(Patient, runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient, rash).

hypothesis(Patient, flu) :-
    symptom(Patient, fever),
    symptom(Patient, headache),
    symptom(Patient, body_ache),
    symptom(Patient, conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient, chills),
    symptom(Patient, sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient, runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient, cough).

hypothesis(Patient, common_cold) :-
    symptom(Patient, headache),
    symptom(Patient, sneezing),
    symptom(Patient, sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient, runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient, chills).

hypothesis(Patient, mumps) :-
    symptom(Patient, fever),
    symptom(Patient, swollen_glands).

hypothesis(Patient, chicken_pox) :-
    symptom(Patient, fever),
    symptom(Patient, chills),
    symptom(Patient, body_ache),
    symptom(Patient, rash).

hypothesis(Patient, measles) :-
    symptom(Patient, cough),
    symptom(Patient, sneezing),
    symptom(Patient, runny_nose).

write_list([]).
write_list([Term| Terms]) :-
    write(Term),
    write_list(Terms).
```

Comment: `use a dynamic predicate` that will work but consider this, [When to use dicts?](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-dicts-usage). Personally I like dicts because they easily convert to/from JSON. ([ref](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=json))

Comment: when I run your code I get the following error: Type error: `oneof([current_input,user_input])' expected, found `user' (an atom)
In:
   [8] throw(error(type_error(...,user),_694))
   [4] pengines_io:pengine_read_line_to_string(user,_750) at /home/swish/lib/swipl/library/pengines_io.pl:372
   [2] read_atom(_804) at  line 16
   [1] go at  line 6

Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization. @slago

Comment: @LauraGonzález The code works perfectly as it is with SWI-PROLOG. For it to work also with SWISH, just change ```user``` to ```user_input``` in the goal ```read_line_to_string(user, String)```. I've updated my answer with this change.

Comment: @GuyCoder I don't see how the problem with backtracking could be solved with dicts.

Comment: @slago I'll take a look.

Comment: @slago There is a problem with the question as posted. See comment for question.

Comment: @GuyCoder The duplicated hypothesis in the code given in the question does not affect the solution for the problem pointed by the OP.

Comment: Thank you guys but I have solved the problem thanks to the first comment that @GuyCoder made. The link had some codes that helped me with my problem.

Comment: @LauraGonzález Nice! But I would like to know why my answer does not solve your problem. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: I really don't know, by running your code I was getting some errors that I don't understand basically cause I'm new to Prolog. Anyways I have a functional code that I can show you but it's in Spanish cause I'm from Spain and I'm writting the code for a subject that is in Spanish. I hope it could help you, if you have a Prolog question I think I will not be able to answer but if you have a language question, ask me hahaha. @slago